# Are turtles lucky

Tags: turtles

As per Hindu mythology or vaastushastra. Is it lucky to keep a turtle as a pet?

I found a turtle by the roadside and my family members say it is lucky as per vastu-shastra. Is it so?

Comment: This question is about luck not, pets.

Comment: I actually voted to close it as opinion. I doubt that anything is scientifically proven; I would be surprised if anyone even attempted to prove or disprove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I am not sure about any history but yes my turtle indeed prove very lucky to me. I had much problems in my house as well as I used to fight everyday with my mother in law. She has a very typical nature. Also my on could not get good marks in his exam. I also had fight often with my husband and I always expected a second child.but we did not have it. Once my brother had brought a turtle from roadside. As he was going outstation I brought baby turtle with me to my home considering it as my another kid. I had read a lot that turtles bring luck to home but I didn't believed in it.

After sometime smoothly everything went good. Me and my mother in law also had good relationship again. The chaos of the house was turn into peace.

I also had a daughter when my son was 22 years old.

Indeed I do believe that if turtles are kept with you as a your own kid they do bring good fortune.